# How to find the mode of a set of data before joining with another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mode

These are the two tables I am looking at:

**k3_alert_types**

```
Type       Description

0            No Show
1            Stop Arrival
2            ...
3            ...
4            ...
5            ...
```

**k3_alert**

```
Type  

1
22
33
2
4
5
65
33
1
```

The tables are just examples, as the actual data sets are much larger. What I would like to do is find the mode of types in the k3_alert table, which I have done with the following:

```
SELECT TYPE , number_of_alerts
FROM
(

    SELECT id, TYPE, COUNT(TYPE) AS number_of_alerts FROM k3_alert
    GROUP BY TYPE
)t1
WHERE number_of_alerts IN
(

    SELECT MAX( count_type ) FROM
    (

        SELECT id, TYPE , COUNT(TYPE ) AS count_type FROM k3_alert
        GROUP BY TYPE
    )t
)
```

I know how to join both tables:

```
SELECT k3_alert_types.description, k3_alert_types.type as type
FROM k3_alert_types
INNER JOIN k3_alert ON k3_alert_types.type = k3_alert.type
ORDER BY type
```

But I don't know how to do both at once.

**I want to see this as the outcome of the whole process (just an example):**

```
Description  Type  number_of_alerts

No Show      1     350
```

Any suggestions?

**edit**: Server type: MariaDB, 
PHP extension: mysql

Comment: I suppose if it was possible to join them, and then filter that would be okay too

Comment: What do you expect to see? Both your queries seem to be grouping on different things. Do you want only the max alerts or all alerts by type?

Comment: Please explain more what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @clinomaniac I want to see the mode of the types from the K3_alert table with how many times the type occurs (number_of_alerts) along with the description of the type

Comment: @AaronDietz Server type: MariaDB , PHP extension: mysql

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT at.description, at.type, COUNT(*) as number_of_alerts
FROM k3_alert_types at
INNER JOIN k3_alert a ON at.type = a.type
GROUP BY at.description, at.type
ORDER BY number_of_alerts DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe this is a very basic question, but where does "a" and "at" come from here? I understand the rest.

Comment: @JakeButo Those are table aliases - you can apply them just like column aliases, and that way you can refer to something shorter than the full table name in your query (`at.type` versus `k3_alert_types.type`)

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was I used a CTE to store the value of mode and then selected top 1. If you wanted more flexibility or have a huge dataset you can use a temp table instead of a CTE.

Below is the code:

```
   DECLARE @AlertType TABLE
(Type1 INT,
Descr varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @AlertType
(
    Type1,
    Descr
)
VALUES
(   1, 'Stop Arrival'),( 0,'No Show')


DECLARE @Alert TABLE
(Type1 INT)
INSERT INTO @Alert
(
    Type1
)
VALUES (1),(0),(1),(23),(1),(5),(1)




;WITH  CTE AS 
(SELECT  Type1, COUNT(*) AS number_of_alerts 
FROM @Alert
GROUP BY Type1
)

SELECT TOP 1 AT.Descr, t1.Type1, t1.number_of_alerts
FROM CTE AS t1
    JOIN @AlertType AS AT
        ON AT.Type1 = t1.Type1  
ORDER BY t1.number_of_alerts DESC
```